# Node - spawn synchronous commands usage

Tags: node.js, electron, spawn

I am writing an electron app that executes a terminal command and writes the output to the app.  If I am only executing one command, this is easy:

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

commandOutput = document.getElementById("command-output") // textarea
status = document.getElementById("status") // div

command = "some"
args = ["command"]
dir = "some/dir"
var child = spawn(command, args, {
    cwd: dir
});

child.on('error', function (err) {
    commandOutput.value += 'error: <' + err + '>';
});

child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
    commandOutput.value += data;
});

child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
    commandOutput.value += 'stderr: <' + data + '>';
});

child.on('close', function (code) {
    status.innerHTML = 'child process exited with code ' + code;
});
```

I like this method since the output is streamed instead of buffered, allowing me to write it to the UI in real time, instead of waiting for the process to finish (it can take some time).  However, I can't figure out a way to spawn multiple, synchronous commands one after the other.  I understand there's a command [spawnSync](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawnsync_command_args_options) that can handle this, but the documentation does not describe how to use it.  Or, if there is a better way, I am open to that as well.

Answer (score 1):

One way you can achieve this is to spawn the next command on the `close` event of the previous command. Assuming your current code, you can use something like this:

```js
child.on ("close", function (code) {
    status.innerHTML = 'child process exited with code ' + code;
    
    // Now spawn the second child
    var secondChild = spawn (secondCmd, secondArgs, { cwd: dir });
    secondChild.on ("error", (err) => { /* error handler */});
    // Register all other handlers as well...
});
```

This is the way to go if you prefer to have your output buffered. Also, you can put all your code spawning processes into a function and call that function on the `close` event, just like so:

```js
function spawnExternalProgram (command, args, dir, next) {
    // Suggestion: Clear the commandOutput field here?

    var child = spawn(command, args, {
        cwd: dir
    });

    child.on('error', function (err) {
        commandOutput.value += 'error: <' + err + '>';
    });

    child.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
        commandOutput.value += data;
    });

    child.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
        commandOutput.value += 'stderr: <' + data + '>';
    });

    child.on('close', function (code) {
        status.innerHTML = 'child process exited with code ' + code;
        next ();
    });
}

spawnExternalProgram ("some", [ "command" ], "some/dir", function () { // 1
    spawnExternalProgram ("some", [ "other", "command" ], "some/dir", function () { //2
        spawnExternalProgram ("yet", [ "another", "command" ], "some/dir", () => {}); // 3
    });
});
```

This will spawn the commands 1, 2 and 3 one after the other once the previous process has exited. The last argument for `next`, namely `() => {}` is equivalent to `function () {}`.

Another option you have is to use, as you already mentioned, `spawnSync`. With this module, you can spawn your processes one after another by a single function call. Please be aware, however, that this might block your UI if you spawn the processes from your renderer process. Usage is similar:

```js
const { spawnSync } = require('child_process');

commandOutput = document.getElementById("command-output")
status = document.getElementById("status")

command = "some"
args = ["command"]
dir = "some/dir"
var childResultOne = spawnSync (command, args, { cwd: dir });

// Check if the process terminated:
var childOneHasTerminated = childResultOne.status === null || childResultOne.status !== 0;

// Access the stdout buffer via the childResultOne object:
var childOneOutput = childResultOne.stdout;

// ---
command = "someOther"
args = ["command", "asWell"]
dir = "some/other/dir"

// Spawn a second child process
var childResultTwo = spawnSync (command, args, { cwd: dir });

// Do all the checks as above.
```

Please note that this will only run the code after the call to `spawnSync` once the process *has exited*, i.e. ran successfully (`status === 0`), has been killed (`status === null && signal !== null`) or crashed (`status !== 0`). This is basically the way a Linux or MacOS Shell or Window's `cmd.exe` would interpret a shell script or a batch file -- one command after another.

Comment: Thank you very much!  I was really hoping to figure out how to do this in using `spawnSync`, but I'm a fan of your nested `spawn` solution, it makes a lot of sense.

Comment: I'm happy this solves your problem! Please be so kind and mark this answer as accepted by clicking the grey check mark icon to indicate that this answers your question.